# Error to install Package in salesforce

Tags: salesforce1-app, managed-package, chatter, package, package-install

I am trying to upgrade a package in a developer org.
I get the following error message:
Error
Package install error
There are problems that prevent this package from being installed.
Problems

Missing Organization Feature: Chatter

Can someone please let me know the root cause for it?

Comment: You need to enable Chatter..... I think the root cause is pretty clear no?

Answer (score 2):

If you [turn on chatter](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_enable.htm&language=en_US) before you install the package the issue should be resolved.

The setting is in **Customize** | **Chatter** | **Settings**.